# CSV file read using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I'm reading data from program(using sc.parallelize) and able to read the data and apply further transformations and actions on that data set.

```
val d = sc.parallelize(Seq(11 -> Seq(21,51,61,111,112), 
                            21 -> Seq(51,111,112,115,116), 
                            31-> Seq(61,111,112,117,121), 
                            41-> Seq(31,111,112,117,122)))

/* d of type val d: RDD[(Int, Seq[Int])]*/

val thes = 2
 val r = d
.flatMapValues(x=>x)
.map(_.swap)
.groupByKey
.map(_._2)
.flatMap(x=>expand(x.toSeq))
.map(_ -> 1)
.reduceByKey(_+_)
.filter(_._2>= thes)
.map(_._1)
.flatMap(x=> Seq(x._1 -> x._2, x._2 -> x._1))
.groupByKey.mapValues(_.toArray)
r.toDF().show() /*giving the expected output*/
```

I'm trying to read the same data set from file and able to read the data but while applying the transformations and actions(same like above), I'm getting cannot cast from string to integer.

```
/*inputfile
 id,sid
 11,"21,51,61,111,112"
 21,"51,111,112,115,116"
 31,"61,111,112,117,121"
 41,"31,111,112,117,122"
 */

val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
.option("header", "true").load(inputFile)
.rdd.map(x=> x.getAs[Int]("id") -> (x.getAs[String]("sid").split(",")
.toList.toSeq).map(_.toInt))

 val thes = 2
 /* df of type val df: RDD[(Int, Seq[Int])]*/

 val r = df
.flatMapValues(x=>x)
.map(_.swap)
.groupByKey
.map(_._2)
.flatMap(x=>expand(x.toSeq))
.map(_ -> 1)
.reduceByKey(_+_)
.filter(_._2>= thes)
.map(_._1)
.flatMap(x=> Seq(x._1 -> x._2, x._2 -> x._1))
.groupByKey.mapValues(_.toArray)

r1.toDF().show()
```

I'm getting cannot cast from string to integer(java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer) during the flatmap operation itself. Even though df is showing of type RDD[(Int, Seq[Int]), not sure where string came into the picture.

```
def expand(seq : Seq[Int]): Seq[(Int, Int)] = 
if (seq.isEmpty) 
Seq[(Int, Int)]() 
else 
seq.tail.map(x=> seq.head -> x) ++ expand(seq.tail)
```

Comment: Somehow I could not find that `.flatMapValues(x=>x)` anywhere? Where is it coming from ? What is your spark version ?

Comment: @Sarvesh Kumar Singh, Function is available ( https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions.scala) and (http://homepage.cs.latrobe.edu.au/zhe/ZhenHeSparkRDDAPIExamples.html#flatMapValues) and can be operated on Pair RDD.  Spark Version : 1.6 and Scala Version : 2.10.6

Comment: `val d = sc.parallelize(Seq(11 -> Seq(21,51,61,111,112), 21 -> Seq(51,111,112,115,116), 31-> Seq(61,111,112,117,121), 41-> Seq(31,111,112,117,122)))          val r1 = d.flatMapValues(x=>x)     r1.foreach(println)` **Result** (11,21)
(11,51)
(11,61)
(11,111)
(11,112)
(21,51)
(21,111)
(21,112)
(21,115)
(21,116)
(31,61)
(31,111)
(31,112)
(31,117)
(31,121)
(41,31)
(41,111)
(41,112)
(41,117)
(41,122)